# おとり用サーバー（ハニーポット）の作り方

Tags: windows, security

インターネットからの不正アクセス（主に高度標的型攻撃）を分析する目的で、おとり用サーバー（いわゆるハニーポット）を作成しました。目的は下記です。
①どこから（IP/プロバイダ/国など）の攻撃が多いか分析
②攻撃に使用されるツールの取得
③C&CサーバーのIP取得

作成にあたり、他のサーバーへ被害が及んではいけないためある程度できることを絞っています。ただそのせいか、攻撃者はサーバーへログオンだけして帰ってしまうようで（サーバーログ上はそう見える）、②、③の目的が達成できません。どうすれば②、③が達成できるでしょうか。それとも普通②、③はやらないのでしょうか。
またハニーポットを構築した方がいれば、参考までに環境をお伺いしたいです。

＜サーバーの環境＞
・OS: Windows 10
・インバウンド通信: 3389/tcpのみ許可 #サーバー外のFWで管理
・アウトバウンド通信: 全遮断 #サーバー外のFWで管理
・RDP可能ユーザー: admin のみ #一般ユーザー、簡単なパスワードを設定
・監査ポリシー: 標準のまま
・Sysmon インストール済
・adminがログオフしたら1分後にネットワーク遮断

Comment: 「攻撃者はサーバーへログオンだけして帰ってしまう」はどのように判断したのでしょうか？

Comment: LocalSessionManagerログで攻撃者がログオンしていた時間帯を特定したあと、次のことを確認しています
・前段に置いてあるFW（CentOSのiptablesで構成）に、DHCPなどのマルチキャストを除くハニーポットからの通信がないこと
・Sysmonのプロセスログに、userinit.exeやtaskhost.exeなど通常ログオン時に自動発生するプロセス以外のプロセスがないこと(見慣れないプロセスの他、cmd,powershell,rdpclipなどがないことも確認)

Comment: 5秒ごとに画面キャプチャをとるツールを作ってみましたが、explorerでダウンロードとかPCとかのタブを見ていっただけみたいです。情報収集だけで、特に踏み台とかにする気は無いんですかね…また色々やってみようと思います